# What am I doing wrong when trying to run the this java test command for LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm attempting to use the [lwjgl](http://lwjgl.org/) library and I'm starting from scratch on a new Windows 7 install.

I downloaded the latest JDK 6 from the Oracle website.  After installing it, I found that commands like "java" or "javac" weren't being recognized from a windows cmd prompt.  So, I edited my path variable and appended the jdk's bin folder to it.

Now the java commands work.

So, I download the latest lwjgl, extract it and read the [installation instructions](http://lwjgl.org/installation.php) on their website:

> Download the distribution Unpack the
>   archive, file contents (in sub
>   folders) should include (amongst other
>   things):
>
> lwjgl.dll lwjglaudio.dll lwjgl.jar
>   lwjgl_util.jar lwjgl_test.jar
>   Test
>   LWJGL by opening a command prompt, and
>   navigating to the folder where the
>   archive was extracted. Once navigated,
>   issue the following command: (all in
>   one line, space before each -option)
>
> java -cp .;res;jar\lwjgl.jar;jar\lwjgl_test.jar;jar\lwjgl_util.jar;jar\lwjgl_fmod3.jar;jar\lwjgl_devil.jar;jar\jinput.jar;-Djava.library.path=native\windows org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest
>
> A window should appear and you should
>   see the following output:
>
> Found  display modes 240, 320,
>   WindowCreationTest Display created
>   Moving to 100, 100 Window created 600,
>   800, Game

So, I extracted it and navigated to the extracted folder in a cmd prompt.

I then executed the test command specified above and I get the following error:

> C:\Users\Nestor\Downloads\lwjgl-2.6\lwjgl-2.6>java
>   -cp .;res;jar\lwjgl.jar;jar\ lwjgl_test.jar;jar\lwjgl_util.jar;jar\lwjgl_fmod3.jar;jar\lwjgl_devil.jar;jar\ji
>   nput.jar;-Djava.library.path=native\windows
>   org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest
>   The
>   following keys are available: ESCAPE: 
>   Exit test ARROW Keys:     Move window
>   when in non-fullscreen mode L:
>   List selectable display modes 0-8:
>   Selection of display modes F:
>   Toggle fullscreen SHIFT-F:
>   Toggle fullscreen with
>   Display.destroy()/create() cycle
>   **Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   lwjgl in java.libr ary.path**
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
>           at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)
>           at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
>           at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:82)
>           at org.lwjgl.Sys.(Sys.java:99)
>           at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.(Display.java:130)
>           at org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest.initialize(WindowCreationTest.java:
>   82)
>           at org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest.main(WindowCreationTest.java:286)
>
> C:\Users\Nestor\Downloads\lwjgl-2.6\lwjgl-2.6>

Why am I getting that error?  I don't understand why there should be linking errors.  In the command that I attempted to execute it clearly spells out the path to those native dll's it needs:

> C:\Users\Nestor\Downloads\lwjgl-2.6\lwjgl-2.6>java
>   -cp .;res;jar\lwjgl.jar;jar\ lwjgl_test.jar;jar\lwjgl_util.jar;jar\lwjgl_fmod3.jar;jar\lwjgl_devil.jar;jar\ji
>   nput.jar;**-Djava.library.path=native\windows**
>   org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest

I've confirmed that the relative path "native\windows" contains those dependencies:

> C:\Users\Nestor\Downloads\lwjgl-2.6\lwjgl-2.6\native\windows>dir
>   Volume in drive C has no label.
>   Volume Serial Number is 2061-75F6
>
> Directory of C:\Users\Nestor\Downloads\lwjgl-2.6\lwjgl-2.6\native\windows
>
> 11/24/2010  12:35 AM              .
>   11/24/2010  12:35 AM              ..
>   10/18/2010  08:44 PM            31,232 jinput-dx8.dll
>   10/18/2010  08:44 PM            65,024 jinput-dx8_64.dll
>   10/18/2010  08:44 PM            29,696 jinput-raw.dll
>   10/18/2010  08:44 PM            62,464 jinput-raw_64.dll
>   10/18/2010  08:44 PM           197,120 lwjgl.dll
>   10/18/2010  08:44 PM           305,664 lwjgl64.dll
>   10/18/2010  08:44 PM            56,832 OpenAL32.dll
>   10/18/2010  08:44 PM           157,184 OpenAL64.dll
>                 8 File(s)        905,216 bytes
>                 2 Dir(s)  155,163,058,176 bytes free

Can anyone help point out what I'm doing wrong? Can anyone reproduce this by downloading the LWJGL library and attempting to run the test command given in the installation instructions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you **do not have a space** between your classpath argument (`-cp jar1.jar;jar2.jar`) and your system property setting (`-D..`).

E.g. your classpath looks like this`-cp .;res;jar\lwjgl.jar;jar\lwjgl_test.jar;jar\lwr...;-Djava.library.path=native\windows`. This way java will interpret your property setting of native library path argument like a classpath!

Just **add a space between those arguments** and you should be up and running, this is the corrected command (also tested on Windows 7):

```
java -cp jar\lwjgl.jar;jar\lwjgl_test.jar;jar\lwjgl_util.jar -Djava.library.path=native\windows org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest
```

*Note that I removed the unused jars from the classpath since you only want to run the `WindowCreationTest` example.*

Answer (score 0):

Check again that directory

```
C:\Users\Nestor\Downloads\lwjgl-2.6\lwjgl-2.6\native\windows
```

exists and contains `lwjgl.dll` and `lwjglaudio.dll`

I believe that something is wrong with your installation, i.e. the directory does not exist or files are not there.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there, because Ive had some issues related to this. Go to your Java/JRE/BIN folder. Right click on Java, and go to properties. Under Privilege Level, check the box by run as an administrator.